# Can I check that two sub query return the same result without using stored procedure?

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
ObjId OtherObjId active (bool)
1          5       0
1          7       1
1          9       0
2          6       0
...
...
...
54         5       0
54         7       1
54         9       0
```

This two queries return an identical result:

```
select OtherObj2,active from MyTable where ObjId1 = 1;

select OtherObj2,active from MyTable where ObjId1 = 54;
```

I would like to run a single query that return return true if the two query result are identical or false if they are not.

The table is a configuration table and I want to test easily if two object have the same configuration. I can perform the check using a store procedure, however I would like to avoid to use it.

I cannot think a way to check it using a query, I am wondering if it is possible.

Any hints?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't know if your DBMS supports [except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) but if it does you can use this.

```
select OtherObjId, active
from MyTable
where ObjId = 1
except
select OtherObjId, active
from MyTable
where ObjId = 54
```

Answer (score 4):

you could use minus

```
(select OtherObj2,active from MyTable where ObjId1 = 1
minus
select OtherObj2,active from MyTable where ObjId1 = 54
)
union
(select OtherObj2,active from MyTable where ObjId1 = 54
minus
select OtherObj2,active from MyTable where ObjId1 = 1
)
```

returns no rows if the result is the same.

(You need both minuses to see if query1 has more rows than query2 or if query2 has more rows than query1)

Answer (score 2):

If your database supports set operations, use [`EXCEPT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) (AKA [`MINUS`](http://oreilly.com/catalog/mastorasql/chapter/ch07.html)):

```
select OtherObj2,active from MyTable where ObjId1 = 1
EXCEPT
select OtherObj2,active from MyTable where ObjId1 = 54
```

This will result in an empty table if both are identical.

Comment: only sql server for this one I believe, Oracle doesn't.

Comment: @daven11 - Oracle calls it `MINUS`.

Comment: You'll find except is different - minus gives the result of A - B, whereas except gives rows that are in one but not the other, which is (A-B) union (B - A).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. If it returns any records, the query results were not identical. If it returns 0 records, there were no mismatches.

```
select 
    OtherObjId, 
    Active
from 
    MyTable
where
    ObjId in (1, 54)
group by
    OtherObjId, 
    Active
having COUNT(*) < 2
```